# Forcing browser to reload favicon not working

Tags: html, caching, favicon

I am working on a site that was a copy of a previous site. I have in the past used the following trick to force the browser to reload the new icon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

But it's not working this time. I have tried different numbers after the v= and for a couple days it showed the old icon; now it's just showing the default document icon (in Chrome).

The file path is correct. What could I be doing wrong? I created the icon using an icon generator (the same one I always use)...

Does this trick not work anymore?

Comment: What mime type does your server send with the favicon?

Comment: I'm looking into this...

Answer (score 0):

You can try CTRL + F5 a couple of times to refresh the browser cache

Comment: I have tried that numerous times and no luck. Even still, I don't want users to have to do that.

Comment: I'm on a Mac in chrome browser.

Comment: I think on a Mac it's CTRL + Shift + F5

Comment: Yup, been doing that.